# How to remove PKCS7 padding from an AES encrypted string in android?

Tags: android, aes

I'm working on a security application using my own customized cryptography method, and having a problem on message decryption.

Here is an my Code

```
private static void myCryptography(){

Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
byte[] input = "Hitesh Dhamshaniya".getBytes();
byte[] keyBytes = "ABCD657865BHNKKK".getBytes();
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

// encryption pass

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
Log.e("==> ", " == > Encode " + Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT));
String encodedStr = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
// decryption pass

cipherText = Base64.decode(encodedStr, Base64.DEFAULT);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ctLength)];
int ptLength = cipher.update(cipherText, 0, ctLength, plainText, 0);
ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
Log.e("==> ", " == > Decoded " + new String(plainText, "UTF-8"));

}
```

Getting below output

== > Encode TteNmufoa5AWWmEPBmQ3N8fdqRpahvwUR7CSclAcsjM=

== > Decoded Hitesh Dhamshaniya���������������������

How to remove unwanted character like '��' from decode string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cipher removes the padding automatically. What you see here comes from the conversion of the byte array `plainText` to the string. You should only use the first `ptLength` bytes instead of the whole array:

```
new String(plainText, 0, ptLength, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please suggest how to get decoded string from it.

Comment: @Hanry: thanks, One more question if I made two different function for encryption and decryption. so that we need ctLength for find ptLength but when function is different we don't have input for find ctLength, is there any other way ?

Comment: I do not really get the question. `ctLength` is the same as `cipherText.length` after you do the base64 decode. You somehow must pass the ciphertext to the decryption function.